# Maven Shade minimizeJar shreds H2 even when configured not to

Tags: maven, h2, maven-shade-plugin

Has anybody ever used maven shade's minimizejar feature while using H2?

Like the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html) I configured the pom.xml file to have minimizejar to ignore H2

```
              <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                   <artifact>com.h2database:h2</artifact>
                   <includes>
                       <include>**</include>
                   </includes>
                </filter>
...
```

minimizeJar shreds H2 and many critical class files are missing (like Driver.class and Engine.class)  This seems to not happen with other packages from Maven.

My full pom.xml is [here](https://github.com/canilao/mc-newsfeed/blob/master/pom.xml) (w/o the minimizeJar feature).

Comment: Have you tried a new version (2.3) of maven-shade-plugin cause in your pom you are using 1.5?

Comment: @khmarbaise I will def give that a try, I didn't know I was out of date there.

Comment: If you take a look on this page: http://maven.apache.org/plugns/ you have an overview of the most up-to-date plugin versions. Furthermore i would suggest to subscribe to the maven-users or at least to maven-announcement list (addresses on maven.apache.org) to be informed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the version of maven-shade was too old.  The feature for ignoring files was deployed in maven-shade 1.6.

> *"As of version 1.6, minimizeJar will respect classes that were*
>   *specifically marked for inclusion in a filter."*